# Capping Values Within A Range

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2013 and I am stuck! I have spent many hours researching on the web and cannot find the answer so I am hoping there is a genius out there who can.

I have a range of data containing payments made for insurance claims `(AV2:AV50000)` and these range from `£0-£300,000`. I am trying to sum the values within this column but capping larger claims at `£50,000`.

This works where there is a claim above £50,000 but not where there isn't one

```
=SUMIFS('Raw Data'!$AV$2:$AV$50000,
    'Raw Data'!$O$2:$O$50000,
    "<=100",
    'Raw Data'!$AV$2:$AV$50000,
    "<50000")
  + IF('Raw Data'!$AV$2:$AV$50000, ">50000", 50000)
```

This works where there isn't one but not where there is

```
=SUMIFS('Raw Data'!$AV$2:$AV$50000,
    'Raw Data'!$O$2:$O$50000,
    ">100",
    'Raw Data'!$O$2:$O$50000,
    "<=200",
    'Raw Data'!$AV$2:$AV$50000,
    "<50000")
  + IF('Raw Data'!$AV$2:$AV$50000,
    ">50000",
    50000*IF('Raw Data'!$AV$2:$AV$50000, ">50000", 'Raw Data'!$AV$2:$AV$50000))
```

Solutions without a helper column gratefully received.

Comment: It is so easy to do with a helper column and I don't see how you can use  `SUMIFS`. It will conditionally add the numbers in your range. It does not allow you to change the numbers to add - only to decide which to include in the sum. Capping involves replacing a number larger than 50,000 to 50,000 when summing.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I was using the SUMIFS to add up claims values <£50,000 where the other range of data that I am looking at is between 100 & 200. I was then trying to use the +IF to cap claim values >£50,000 and add them to the SUMIF

Answer (score 1):

An array formula might work for you here...

So select some data cell and enter this formula...

```
=SUM(IF(AV:AV>50000;50000;AV:AV))
```

Then create an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should see curly braces around the formula...

Might be a bit slow, but should work...

Comment: 50K rows is a lot of rows but it is still substantially less than 1,048,576 rows. Best to limit the calculation to the extent of the data with array formulas; e.g. `=SUM(IF(o2:index(o:o; match(1e99; av:av))<=100;IF(av2:index(av:av; match(1e99; av:av))>50000;50000;av2:index(av:av; match(1e99; av:av)))))`

Comment: or even: =SUM(IF(AV2:AV50000>50000;50000;AV2:AV50000)) ..... :)
By the way Martin, you possibly should restructure your formula to deal with non numerics -i.e. Errors and strings etc to return 0. Depends really on your worksheet..

Comment: Neither of those worked I'm afraid, looks like the helper column then! Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure? Works for me and I'll be surprised if a simple formula like that doesn't work. My suspicion is, you are not creating an array formula, or you have some failure due to errors in the range...

Comment: Oh, btw: I'm using a German locale. If this doesn't work for you try replacing ; with , in the formula :)